# Were the HMS Bounty footprints inspired by crop circles?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu, the-voyage-home

In *The Voyage Home*, the former Klingon Bird of Prey "HMS Bounty" leaves very visible footprints/indentations due to its mass, in a clearing in a park in San Francisco. The cloaked landing and the formation of the depressions frighten a couple of city waste collectors.

[image: indentations in the grass]

These footprints are essentially (non-circular) "crop circles".

**Were the writers inspired by the mania / interest surrounding crop circles (as possible markings left by extraterrestrial vessels) in the second half of the 80s?**

**Also, is there any reference in the Star Trek Extended Universe to these footprints left behind by the Bounty?**

Comment: Note: My question is not about why park-goers didn't seem to bump into the cloaked ship more often, or at least have baseballs etc. bounce off of it.  :-)

Comment: Although that's actually a pretty good question.

Comment: They were essentially crop circles, apart from the fact that they weren’t in a crop, and they weren’t circles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no references to the footprints (as far as I'm aware) in any other EU properties, but the scorched earth circle *is* mentioned in the [official novelisation](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home_%28novel%29). The two council workers; Javy and Ben return to the park on several occasions in the hopes of getting another glimpse of their elusive vision. When the ship finally takes off, leaving only a burn-mark on the ground they decide not to tell anyone about it, for fear of being dismissed as cranks.

> "I saw it," Javy said. "I saw its shadow, anyway." "But, I mean, we would of seen it and we would of been able to show it to other people. To a reporter, maybe, and they'd write us up in a book and maybe we'd get on Johnny Carson." He brightened. "Maybe if we show them the burned place-"
>
> **"Maybe if we show them the burned place, they'll arrest us for arson. Or they'll write us up as a couple of nut cases,"** Javy said. "And maybe they'd be right. **We don't have any proof. A burned place and a shadow."**
>
> "I'm really sorry," Ben said again, downcast. "Don't be, Ben, it's okay, honest."
>
> "I'd be mad, if I were you."
>
> "Maybe I ought to be," Javy said. "Except ... " He hesitated, not sure he wanted to say it out 'loud before he was certain it was true.
>
> "What?"
>
> What the hell. Telling Ben the story had always worked before. Javy grinned. "I figured out how to end my novel," he said.

Comment: Great answer, as usual! :-)